# Order of acidity in aromatic molecules with various functional groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

What factors need to be considered in order to rank the acidity of aromatic molecules with various substituents?

> Given benzene with 1 $\ce{OH}$ group. How does adding the following functional groups affect acidity, and what are the rules to determine this?
>
> - an additional $\ce{OH}$ group
> - $\ce{Cl}$
> - $\ce{NO2}$
> - $\ce{NO2 + Cl}$
> - $2\times\ce{NO2}$ groups
> - $3\times\ce{NO2}$ groups

Based on what I know about acids, the following increase acidity:

- charge - the less electrons, the more acidic (more able to grab hydrogen)
- electronegativy increases.
- compounds with more resonance (more double and triple bonds) - more stability.
- more electron withdrawing groups.
- lower orbitals - the more s character (less p,d,f), the closer the electrons are to the nucleus, and the lower the energy, which means more stability.

The following decreases acidity

- steric hindrance - where 3D structure of a molecule make solvent less accessible, and thus more weakly stabilised. (The difference may be small)
- larger molecules tend to require a larger number of solvent molecules to solvate them.

Comment: Draw the resonance structures for each of the molecules.